# How to integrate swagger with jersey + spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using springboot + jersey for web restful implementation. Now I am going to integrate swagger into our application.  I did following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfiguration(){
        register(HelloworldAPI.class);
        configureSwagger();
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.cooltoo.api");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

I added following dependences on build.gradle:

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:'+springfoxSwaggerVersion)
compile('io.springfox:springfox-petstore:'+springfoxSwaggerVersion)
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:'+springfoxSwaggerVersion)
compile('io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.8')
```

I was able to launch the web application but I wander which url is for swagger? I tried with http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080/swagger, and http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. But none of them could be accessed.

Comment: Does your application have a context root? It should be available at swagger-ui.html relative to the context root.

Comment: The context root is just "/".

Answer (score 12):

I think `@EnableSwagger2` annotation and `springfox` dependencies would work if the endpoints are implemented using Spring MVC instead of a JAX-RS implementation.

I blogged about this a few months ago, [Microservices using Spring Boot, Jersey Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html)

Basically if you need to document your Jersey-implemented endpoints, you would need to:

1)
Make sure your Spring Boot app scans for components located in specific packages (ie com.asimio.jerseyexample.config) via:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {
        "com.asimio.jerseyexample.config", "com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest"
    }
)
```

2) Jersey configuration class implementation:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.config;
...
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.jersey.application-path:/}")
    private String apiPath;

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // Register endpoints, providers, ...
        this.registerEndpoints();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Register components where DI is needed
        this.configureSwagger();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        this.register(HelloResource.class);
        // Access through /<Jersey's servlet path>/application.wadl
        this.register(WadlResource.class);
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        // Available at localhost:port/swagger.json
        this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
        this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        config.setConfigId("springboot-jersey-swagger-docker-example");
        config.setTitle("Spring Boot + Jersey + Swagger + Docker Example");
        config.setVersion("v1");
        config.setContact("Orlando L Otero");
        config.setSchemes(new String[] { "http", "https" });
        config.setBasePath(this.apiPath);
        config.setResourcePackage("com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1");
        config.setPrettyPrint(true);
        config.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

3) Resource implementation using JAX-RS (Jersey) and Swagger annotations:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1;
...
@Component
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "Hello resource", produces = "application/json")
public class HelloResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloResource.class);

    @GET
    @Path("v1/hello/{name}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets a hello resource. Version 1 - (version in URL)", response = Hello.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Hello resource found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Hello resource not found")
    })
    public Response getHelloVersionInUrl(@ApiParam @PathParam("name") String name) {
        LOGGER.info("getHelloVersionInUrl() v1");
        return this.getHello(name, "Version 1 - passed in URL");
    }
...
}
```

4) Make sure your app's Spring Boot configuration file makes a distinction between Spring MVC (for actuator endpoints) and Jersey (for resources) endpoints:

**application.yml**

```
...
# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than Jersey's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)
server.servlet-path: /
# Jersey dispatcher servlet
spring.jersey.application-path: /api
...
```

Comment: Can confirm this works. Seems like at least the @Api-Annotation is necessary for the Resource to get picked up during the scan. To also serve the static swagger-ui from a jersey + spring-boot app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882044/how-to-add-swagger-related-static-files-to-spring-boot-jersey-app

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use rather old version of springfox, but now (for version 2.4.0) it must be configured very different from your code, see http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

For example, I have the following springfox configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    Docket rsApi() {
        new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_12)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage('com.test.service'))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping('/')
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title('Test API')
            .description('Test API')
            .version('0.0.10.SNAPSHOT')
            .termsOfServiceUrl('')
            .contact('Test company')
            .license('Public')
            .licenseUrl('http://example.com/')
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for SpringMVC, not for Jersey (jax-rs). As we see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004323/976948