# How to integrate springfox-swagger2 with jersey in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using springboot with jersey as restful API. Now I want to integrate swagger2 into my project but it doesn't work. When I run my application and access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. I got the swagger web page but no api is showing(see below image). It seems that swagger didn't find my api classes.

[image]

Below is the dependencies I added.

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.0"
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0'
```

Below is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.ticket.api")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Docket documentation() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.lenovo.ticket.api"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())

                .build().pathMapping("/")
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }

}
```

Below is my jersey config class:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/ticket")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig  {

    public JerseyConfig(){
        register(Helloworld.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey isn't supported, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640863/springfox-swagger-no-api-docs-with-spring-boot-jersey-and-gardle/38004323#38004323). Given that the answer comes from SpringFox library's author, I'd say the info is solid.

Answer (score 1):

As previously answered in this thread, `@EnableSwagger2` annotation and `springfox` dependencies would work if the endpoints are implemented using Spring MVC instead of Jersey.

In order to document your Jersey-implemented endpoints:

1)
Make sure your Spring Boot app scans for components located in specific packages (ie com.asimio.jerseyexample.config) via:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {
        "com.asimio.jerseyexample.config", "com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest"
    }
)
```

2) Jersey configuration class implementation:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.config;
...
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.jersey.application-path:/}")
    private String apiPath;

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // Register endpoints, providers, ...
        this.registerEndpoints();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Register components where DI is needed
        this.configureSwagger();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        this.register(HelloResource.class);
        // Access through /<Jersey's servlet path>/application.wadl
        this.register(WadlResource.class);
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        // Available at localhost:port/swagger.json
        this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
        this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        config.setConfigId("springboot-jersey-swagger-docker-example");
        config.setTitle("Spring Boot + Jersey + Swagger + Docker Example");
        config.setVersion("v1");
        config.setContact("Orlando L Otero");
        config.setSchemes(new String[] { "http", "https" });
        config.setBasePath(this.apiPath);
        config.setResourcePackage("com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1");
        config.setPrettyPrint(true);
        config.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

3) Resource implementation using JAX-RS (Jersey) and Swagger annotations:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1;
...
@Component
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "Hello resource", produces = "application/json")
public class HelloResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloResource.class);

    @GET
    @Path("v1/hello/{name}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets a hello resource. Version 1 - (version in URL)", response = Hello.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Hello resource found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Hello resource not found")
    })
    public Response getHelloVersionInUrl(@ApiParam @PathParam("name") String name) {
        LOGGER.info("getHelloVersionInUrl() v1");
        return this.getHello(name, "Version 1 - passed in URL");
    }
...
}
```

4) Make sure your app's Spring Boot configuration file makes a distinction between Spring MVC (for actuator endpoints) and Jersey (for resources) endpoints:

**application.yml**

```
...
# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than Jersey's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)
server.servlet-path: /
# Jersey dispatcher servlet
spring.jersey.application-path: /api
...
```

These steps are better detailed in a blog post I created some time ago, [Microservices using Spring Boot, Jersey Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html)

It references source code in my Bitbucket repo and a running example