# How to add Swagger related static files to Spring Boot + Jersey app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to add Swagger support to my REST API but I am confused how to add Swagger related static content (HTML, JS) files to my Spring Boot application.

**I use the following dependencies:**

- `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.1.RELEASE`
- `spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.0.1.RELEASE`
- `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.18`

**This is my swagger configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public BeanConfig swaggerConfiguration() {
        final BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("a.b.c");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        return beanConfig;
    }
}
```

**And the jersey configuration:**

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(ImageResource.class);
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    }
}
```

This part works like a charm, when I open http://localhost:8090/swagger.json then I can see the expected Swagger JSON content.

But I do not know, how to add the Swagger related static HTML content to my application. I can see that this content is in the `springfox-swagger-ui.jar` and I can add it to my project as a maven dependency, but how I can unpack the content from this jar?

And what is the proper way to overwrite the default swagger.json URL with my URL in the static Swagger file in order to Swagger show my REST API immediately when I open `swagger-ui.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Please, do not include `springfox-swagger-ui.jar`, it's meant to work with `Spring`'s `RestController`.

Comment: This is the full URL of the swagger-ui: http://localhost:8080/myapp/webjars/swagger-ui/3.13.3/index.html. The short URL (http://localhost:8080/myapp/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html) does not work. Bug report: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11355

Comment: You might improve the accessibility by defining your own servlet filter that redirects /swagger-ui.html and /swagger-ui to something like `webjars/swagger-ui/VERSION/index.html?url=/yourBasePath/swagger.json` - the url-Query-Param will additionally set up the swagger-ui to initialize with your api spec url instead of the default petstore one.

Answer (score -1):

You must have solved it now but it might help others so here's the complete procedure as I was also looking for a tutorial.

I am using `Swagger V2` with `Spring Boot 2` and it's straightforward 3 step process.

**Step 1:** Add required dependencies in `pom.xml` file. The second dependency is optional use it only if you need `Swagger UI`.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Step 2:** Add configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

     public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact("Usama Amjad", "https://stackoverflow.com/users/4704510/usamaamjad", "hello@email.com");
      public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = new ApiInfo("Article API", "Article API documentation sample", "1.0", "urn:tos",
              DEFAULT_CONTACT, "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", new ArrayList<VendorExtension>());

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Set<String> producesAndConsumes = new HashSet<>();
        producesAndConsumes.add("application/json");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                .produces(producesAndConsumes)
                .consumes(producesAndConsumes);

    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Setup complete and now you need to document APIs in `controllers`

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a list Articles for a given Author", response = Article.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found") })
    @GetMapping(path = "/articles/users/{userId}")
    public List<Article> getArticlesByUser() {
       // Do your code
    }
```

**Usage:**

**Swagger UI:** You can access it via `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

[image]

**Postman:** You can also access your Documentation `JSON` from `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` and just copy paste it in Postman to use with it.

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution for Jersey.