# Is it possible to serve the swagger root from a sub path as opposed to the applcation context root?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I followed this example [swagger configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640850/107301) but would like to set the swagger root (the path with which the swagger.json is served) to `<jersey-context-root>/api-or-some-other-path` except that no matter what I pass to the `config.setBasePath(some-sub-path);` the swagger root is always the j**ersey app-context root** defined in the application.yml file, i.e: `spring.jersey.application-path`so it seems the **basePath** is hard-wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your link and the code

```java
this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
```

That [`ApiListingResource`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/v1.5.21/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/ApiListingResource.java) is the actual resource class that serves up the `swagger.json` endpoint. If you look at the link, you can see the class is annotated with the path (the `{type:json|yaml}` determines what type if data you will get back).

```java
@Path("/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
```

If you want to change the path, you need to register it differently. What you need to do is use the `Resource.builder(ResourceClass)` method to get a builder where we can change the path. For example you can do something like this.

```java
Resource swaggerResource = Resource.builder(ApiListingResource.class)
        .path("foobar/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
        .build();
```

Then instead of the the `ResourceConfig#register()` method, you use the `ResourceConfig#registerResource(Resource)` method.

```java
this.registerResource(swaggerResource);
```

---

Here's a complete test using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ResourceBuilderTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
    public static class ApiListingResource {

        @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String get() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        Resource swaggerResource = Resource.builder(ApiListingResource.class)
                .path("foobar/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
                .build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.registerResources(swaggerResource);
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        Response response = target("foobar/swagger.json")
                .request()
                .get();

        String data = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(data);
        assertEquals("Hello World!", data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, though I have decided to leverage the [holon platform](https://docs.holon-platform.com/5.2.0-alpha2/reference/holon-jaxrs.html#introduction) to manage Jersey and Swagger